# stream adapters and backing store streams

Tags: c#, .net

We know that backing store streams such as FileStream deal exclusively in bytes, therefore we need stream adapters to wrap backing store streams.

so let's say we use a StreamReader as:

```
// the data.txt only contains 3 chars in one line
using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText("data.txt"))
{
  string input = null;
  while ((input = r.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Can I say even though the StreamReader r only issues ReadLine() once, underlying there is a FileStream xxx(wrapped by StreamReader ) issues ReadByte() 3 times?

Comment: You can find out exactly how it works by [reading the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L737). [ReadBuffer()](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L566) is here.

Comment: Eventually it seems to end up [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs#L1073-L1079) via [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L2486), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1569) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1497).

Comment: @John  Thank you for your links, but I'm not a senior developer, could you just tell me that in my case, whether a StreamReader's ReadLine() trigger multiple FileStream's ReadByte()?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @John could you have a look at this question, please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050919/how-classdata-attribute-passes-data-to-a-test-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no: neither `StreamReader` nor `FileStream` call `ReadByte()` repeatedly. They do, however call [`Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_), which returns a number of bytes rather than a single byte at a time.

This is about as deep as it gets within C#, as it eventually gets routed into a call to Kernel32's [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile), whose signature looks like this:

```
BOOL ReadFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPVOID       lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

To verify this, we can start the journey at `StreamReader`'s [ReadLine method](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L737):

- `ReadLine()` calls `StreamReader`'s [`ReadBuffer()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L566)
- `ReadBuffer()` calls the `Stream`'s [`Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L575) method, which given how [`File.OpenText(...)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L45) creates the `StreamReader` is a [`FileStream`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L227).
- `FileStream`'s [`Read(...)` method](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1497) calls `FileStream`'s [`ReadCore(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1520) method.
- [`ReadCore(...)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1569) calls `FileStream`'s [`int ReadFileNative(SafeFileHandle handle, byte[] bytes, int offset, int count, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, out int hr)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L1589) method.
- [`ReadFileNative(...)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L2486) calls the static [`int ReadFile(SafeFileHandle handle, byte* bytes, int numBytesToRead, IntPtr numBytesRead_mustBeZero, NativeOverlapped* overlapped)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L2511) method of `Win32Native`.
- Win32Native's [`ReadFile(...)`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs#L1075) method calls out to Kernel32.dll.

Note: This is from looking at the .NET Framework code. Presumably the .NET Core code is equivalent, but not exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. FileStream's Read(...) method is called, that's the answer I was looking for. Another question is about short counts when reading frim Stream, my textbook says I needs to do a "while loop read". does this only apply to specified stream such as network stream, I don't need to do while loop read when reading from a FileStream which will never have a short count problem?am I correct?

Comment: @slowjams You might get less bytes with a `FileStream` if you're at byte 10000 of a 10128 byte file and you request to read 8192 bytes. When using `Read`, you should always read until you either a) already have all of the data you need, or b) `Read` returns 0 bytes. `ReadLine` in `StreamReader` wraps this logic up for you, so you don't have to worry about it. Note that `ReadLine` will return `null` if there is no more data to read.

Comment: so I can also tell by the the int (let's say it is `int sum`) return by the `FileStream.Read(...)`, if sum <= 8192, then I know I have read all content of the file, so I can avoid to issue another `FileStream.Read(...)` and let it return 0, which cause overhead?

Comment: @slowjams You can only tell if you know how much you've read in total, and the full length of the `Stream` (which is only available if the Stream's `CanSeek` property is `true`). The best practice is to read until the returned `int` is 0.

Comment: sorry I'm a fussy person:)    I know read until the returned int is 0 brings peace of mind, but I only need to know the stream is seekable, I don't even need to know its length, so I issue a 1,000 bytes read first, if return int sum is < 1000, I know immediately I have read all the content, if sum = 1000, I just issue another read ...until returned sum is < 1000. let's say on the third read, returned sum is 500, I know I can stop now. there is overhead to issue another read and get a return of 0, isn't it?

Comment: @slowjams I think we're coming at this from different perspectives. As far as I'm aware, yes your logic is fine for `FileStream`. My recommendation is that you write your code for the general case, lest you decide a year or two from now to do some refactoring, change your method to take a `Stream`, and then suddenly encounter weird bugs that might be hard to track down and explain.

Comment: `returned sum is 500, I know I can stop now.` No you can't @slowjams. **Don't rely on current implementations**. The docs are super clear on this, as I pointed out in your other question. The overhead to issuing another read is minimal and is **required** according to the docs. So just do it, and be safe.